# Photos and iCloud cannot see photos on iCloud safe to delete?

Tags: mac, icloud, backup, macos

I want to delete photos from my Mac to free up space. I've never gone to iCloud before to check on my back ups and just assumed they occurred. However when i go to iCloud it shows nothing but find phone. Is there a way to see photos? The only question i see that actually addresses this is negatively voted on, and the only answer did not address the Question but was geared toward organizing library and space on cloud. I just want to know my stuff is there. How? if I cannot see it??

Comment: never come to this site, so sorry if i sound stupid. all research indicates iCloud should look similar to my dock, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that iCloud is for storage of photos, and not just for synchronization; otherwise, why would you have the option to purchase more space (which I have done). That being said, @Jaime Santa Cruz is correct in that you cannot back up Time Machine to iCloud, but you should be able to indefinitely store photos, docs, notes, etc., so long as you keep within the storage limit or purchase (and continue to pay) for additional storage.

I had the same problem and actually wrote a question about it just the other day and received a number or comments and an answer. [Deleting Photos, what iCloud saves and how to access things from iCloud and device storage issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200370/deleting-photos-what-icloud-saves-and-how-to-access-things-from-icloud-and-devi) It seemed clear from what others were saying that I should be able to see icons in iCloud, such as photos, and when you click on/open these tabs you should be able to see your photos/docs. I could not.

It was suggested I contact Apple support if there was nothing there aside from Find My Phone (which there was not - sounds like this is what you are saying). I did contact Apple and sure enough, there was a problem on iCloud/Apple's end and they need to remotely reset my iCloud account(this is the word they used, from a  technical perspective I have no clue what was wrong or what they did to fix it), but after about 15 minutes with them iCloud appeared as it should and never had before. There was an orange background with most of the app icons that appear on the dock, and I could now view my photographs and documents, etc.

If iCloud is turned on, your devices are synced and you are going to iCloud.com and getting a black background with just a FMP, you probably need to do what I did.

Comment: i noticed this question and it seemed you were asking the same...i was even afraid to ask because i saw you got a negative for asking...but this is my problem. I read the answer you got but that was about storage on iCloud so i thought either that person did not understand what you were saying or i ws reading it wrong. but now i know you may be right. i will call apple and LUK

Comment: Good luck. I looked like an idiot and did get a down vote, but at least I realized that iCloud was not acting as it should. Let us know if this works. Don't be surprised if a more senior user ends up saying your question is too similar to another. You should edit for grammar. This site is quite picky about using caps when appropriate, not using text lingo, and using proper punctuation. Otherwise, someone else probably will :~) .

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) on your Mac, and your photos are on the Photos app, you can set it up to save originals on the cloud and automatically save space by keeping a lower resolution copy on your Mac.
To do this, go to Preferences > iCloud, then select "Optimize".

This will also allow you to view your entire collection on iCloud.com if you wish.

Note that you have no saying on when the app starts "saving space" on your behalf, and that if you delete a photo on your Mac it will be deleted on iCloud too; it is more a synchronization service than a storage on the cloud service, with the advantage of the space optimization.

Also, there is no Mac iCloud backup service to my knowledge; you can only backup to Time Machine —or some other backup service of your preference, of course. You may have some of your documents synchronized to iCloud but if you delete them locally they will also be deleted there.
Time Machine erases old backups when it runs out of space, so it won't work as a long term storage solution either, unless you have lots of space available —so it does not need to delete your old backups in order to make space for the new ones.

Comment: @gracey209 It was reset and works fine now! I called the store and the genius bar techpeople said it was a bug that affected a certain number of users who got iCloud so now its fine. thanks u